# FNVEdit merged patch, fixing it and advices/tips?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

So, I use FNVEdit 3.0.30 (latest to the date) to create a merged patch for Fallout New Vegas, its idea is to auto-mix mods.

1) The problem is the groups `Containers` and `Factions` got messed; entries were missing... All other groups seems ok!? How to be sure? I just remove such groups from the merged patch. Any advice?

2) How to remove/delete items from containers on FNVEdit? I right click and click on `Remove` but the entry wont go away, is it bugged or is there some other way to do that? I press `del key` but nothing happens either...

EDIT: 3) And how to remove a master reference from an esp file? no matter what I do, the reference wont go away...

I know these are many questions, I wonder if there is some guide somewhere with all that stuff explained?

If you know one or other answer, it is ok, I will like it too :)

Comment: You might find the [FNVEdit Training Manual](http://newvegas.nexusmods.com/mods/38413/?) helpful.

Comment: thx! I've managed also to run a few pascal scripts (eek, but works) to batch update/fix data on fields!

Answer (score 1):

There was about 15 dead FNVEdit processes, look at Ctrl+Shift+ESC on Windows XP, after restarting it several times...

I believe it was the cause of that inconsistent FNVEdit behavior.

To fix that, just boot the machine; ALL problems VANISHED!